# jbimages plugin for TinyMCE not working on godaddy

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

I'm using TinyMCE and the jbimages plugin to upload images directly with the help of TinyMCE. It works on localhost but when I test it at godaddy, I receive following error message:

```
Upload in progress…
This is taking longer than usual.
An error may have occurred.
View script's output
No input file specified.
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have proper directory permissions on the server?
Make sure you have the upload directory permissions set as 777
This will allow read/write to that directory

EDIT: TRY REPLACING THE ACTION WITH

```
action=”ci/index.php?/upload/{#jbimages_dlg.lang_id}”
```

NOTICE THE **?**

Comment: yes i do, Debugging shows it’s looking for tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/jbimages/ci/index.php/upload/english, which does not exist.

Looking at dialog.htm, it appears to be hard-coded in the form action:
action=”ci/index.php/upload/{#jbimages_dlg.lang_id}”
I’ve tried putting htaccess with mod-rewrite commands in jbimages folder, modifying permission on upload folder, etc. and still not working. :(

Comment: try replacing it by action=”ci/index.php?/upload/{#jbimages_dlg.lang_id}”

Comment: @SamBattat I am also getting this error. I am using Zend Framework 2 and I have used TinyMCE with jbimages plug-in. and when I click on image icon; dialog do appear but in debugger it shows "404 not found" for "/jbimages/ci/index.php/blank." Is it possible that there is some kind of .htaccess issue?

Comment: It's amazing to see what a single '?' question mark symbol can do... thanks a lot!